# Key binding to create unordered list in Microsoft Word without changing font?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, fonts, key-binding

I'd like to use a key binding to create an unordered list in MS Word.

I know that `CTRL-SHIFT-L` will create the list, but it will always change the font to Microsoft Sans Serif. How can I change this to use a different font? We only use Verdana here, for instance.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> applies the *List Bullet* style.

Modify the *List Bullet* style to use Verdana as the font and everywhere you have applied this style the font will change.

[image: Modify Style screen]

Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> on a bulleted item and Word will display a window showing the current style. Click on the Modify... button to change that style.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! You've opened up a new world to me...